# How to combine API GET request in c#?

Tags: c#, optimization, queue, rest

I have some folders, and some folders have counts with GET request GetFoldersCount="api/folders/{id}/count", which runs at a specific interval. Interval can be different for each folder. So, how can I optimally organize a queue in the controller to collect and execute multiple requests, rather than each separately?

Comment: I don't know what is the scale of application, but message queues like Kafka and RabbitMQ can do this very well.

Comment: Can you share some code of what you're currently doing? This sounds like some work for a batch job and not something that should be part of a web API.

Comment: Please check  [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)